# Can I use the existing document field value in the $push of mongodb ?, I tried the below approach , its not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.getCollection('test').update({
  "b_id": "3"
},
{
      "$push": {"books": {
        "status": "available",
        "shelf_id": "$shelf_id",
        "rack_no": "$rack_no",
        "book_id": new ObjectId()
      }
  }
})
```

shelf_id and rack_no are already available in the document. Here, I need to create the array "books" which includes status, shelf_id, rack_no and book_id.

I am not able to get the existing value of shelf_id and rack_no in this case. It considers $rack_id as string instead the value from the document. Please suggest a way.

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: It's 4.2 @ambianBeing

Comment: Is `books` field an array? Can u please update the question with sample document and expected output.

Comment: `books` is a new field which has to be added to all documents. Document contains other fields along with the `rack_id` @ambianBeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in MongoDB 4.2, using the pipeline form of update, but not with $push.

Passing an array of pipeline stages as the second argument to update will allow you to use aggregation operators.

The [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html#push-aggregation) aggregation operator behaves very differently from the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#push) update operator, so in a pipeline use `$set` with `$concatArrays`, like:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({
  "b_id": "3"
},
[{$set:
    {
      books: {$concatArrays:[
                "$books",
                [{
                  "status": "available",
                  "shelf_id": "$shelf_id",
                  "rack_no": "$rack_no",
                  "book_id": new ObjectId()
                }]
      ]}
    }
}])
```

Comment: I am getting error at `}}` - I am trying to figure out - could you please help me? And will it work if array doesn't exist? - I figured out - it's an extra `}` at the end. And if `books` array is not there, we can use `[]` instead `$books`

Comment: I am not able to do updateMany - It says `the update operation document must contain atomic operators` Could you please help me?

Comment: One of the `}` should have been `]`

Comment: Is there any way to get unique object ids for each document 's book_id attribute by doing this way?